# Is there a shortcut to summing fractional powers?

Tags: summation

I'm trying to solve a problem where, incrementally, each step sums a particular value. The value is plagued with an ugly fractional power. Is there a shortcut to something like $$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{i/7}$$

I mean, I know this is going to mean $2^{1/7} + 2^{2/7} + ... 2^{n/7}$ but I don't see an easy way to shortcut it. I basically want to just do $f(n) = blah$ without defining it as $f(n) = f(n-1) + blah$.

I will be solving this for a *finite* $n$, with no value n over 200. In fact, I have the solution for each value. I just want to calculate it without iterating the entire solution every time, or storing the solution.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^{i/7}=\color{red}{2^0}+2^{1/7}+2^{2/7}+\cdots+2^{n/7}$.

Comment: That is a mistake on my part. It should actually start at 1. Ooops.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If you look at it close enough, you will see that this is a geometric sum.

Answer (score 1):

What you want should be

$$\sum_{i=0}^na^i=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$
for $a\not=1,0$. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Geometric_series#Formula) for more information)
 Now set $a=2^{\frac 17}$.

Comment: If you don't assume $0^0=1$, you'll need to add $a\neq 0$ too.

Comment: @user26486: OK, I added $a\not=0$.